# Should I switch my $ variables to literal values for bundle identifier for Auth0 1.6.0?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, auth0, info-plist

I'm following [this guide](https://github.com/auth0/react-native-auth0) for configuring Auth0 for React Native. In the section about `CFBundleURLSchemes`, it says "The  value should be the literal value of the Bundle Identifier with no $ variables" and in its example the value is `<string>org.reactjs.native.example.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)</string>`. In my app I have `<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>` where `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` is defined in my `project.pbxproj` file. This worked with the previous version of Auth0.

**What I Want To Know:**

1) Am I correct that I should switch my `<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>` for `<string>org.reactjs.native.example.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)</string>`?

2) In the previous section of the article it says to *locate* the above value for `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` by looking at the following lines in `Info.plist`:

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>org.reactjs.native.example.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)</string>
```

In my `Info.plist`, I instead have:

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
```

where again `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` refers to the variable stored in `project.pbxproj`. Should I change this too, swapping

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
```

for

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>org.reactjs.native.example.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)</string>
```

?

Comment: The `$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)` will resolve to your App name. eg: com.cool.DemoApp in this case  DemoApp is the `$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)`. `com.cool.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)` and `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)` are the same, both will result to `com.cool.DemoApp`.